# Frequent Solar Eclipse Cycle and Its Effects

Tags: weather, day-night, seasons, eclipses

I’m trying to imagine a sci-fi/fantasy world in which a solar eclipse occurs roughly once every 3 or 4 days. The exact frequency can be arbitrary and varied, but it does need to occur often. I would like to get an idea of the resulting descriptions of time intervals, weather patterns, and seasonal changes that occur. Could anyone help me figure this out mathematically or point me to a resource that could help?

Comment: I think setting the story on the moon of a gas giant should suffice for the frequency of the solar eclipses, but I'm not sure about the rest.

Comment: You're asking a lot of distinct questions. Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: @Halfthawed - that is a good answer.  Plus if you go find data about eclipses on the Jovian moons then I can just read what you bring and don't have to find it myself.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by eclipse? Do you want the apparent size of the sun and moon to be the same, or would you allow the eclipsing body to be apparently bigger, say a gas giant the world is a moon of? If the former, this is impossible - the best you can get is about a month, and only if you're very, very precise. In the latter case, the tolerances are much greater, and you can get down to around a week (the orbital period of Io), maybe less.

Comment: You could do a hell of a lot with this. You may want to determine some more distinct information about your solar system. For example:  Are there multiple moons? Are there multiple suns? Do you have an idea of how you want the seasons to progress? How long is the day night cycle? How long is a year? How big is the planet compared to Earth? You could have dozens or hundreds of possible combinations of that data that result in what appears to be frequent eclipses.

Answer (score 1):

No additional effect I suppose.
You simply will have a mini-night every X days, the frequent solar eclipse should not add any effect outside the one already present (but not strictly related to the eclipse itself).

Comment: I agree - people, and all plants/animals would have adjusted to this ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Willk who actually inspired me to hunt for a moon.

**It's Europa!**

Turns out that you and Arthur C. Clarke think alike. Europa is a tidally locked moon of Jupiter with an orbital period of roughly 3.5 days, which gives you your solar eclipse every 3.5 days. Unfortunately, this isn't in Europa days, since Europa is tidally locked to Jupiter, that means that a Europa 'day' is equivalent to it's orbital period. Not to mention that since we're dealing with the moon of a gas giant, there are a whole host of other problems that you'll have to deal with. Luckily for me, we have a one-question-per-post policy, so all I need to do is tell you that you want a gas giant with a moon like Europa, and the solar eclipse won't have that much of an effect. Since the planet is tidally locked, it'll be hitting the exact same spot every time, so that very spot will be adjusted a little for it, but aside from that, not a lot of effects.

Good luck figuring out all the rest of the things you'll need to have a survivable gas giant moon!

Comment: *"It'll be hitting the exact same spot every time":* Hmmm. The *entire* Europa goes into the shadow of Jupiter, and it takes quite some time for it to emerge. Jupiter is bigggg, Europa is tiny. The "spot" covers the entire satellite.